# Getting all substring before first 4 characters after second occurence in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'URL': ['https://weibo.com/6402575118/Iy0zjtMNZ', 'https://weibo.com/6402575118/Hellothere', 'https://weibo.com/6402575118/hithere']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['URL'])
```

I want to get all substring up to the fourth character after the second occurence of "/" such that:

```
data = {'URL': ['https://weibo.com/6402575118/Iy0z', 'https://weibo.com/6402575118/Hell', 'https://weibo.com/6402575118/hith']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['URL'])
```

how do I achieve that?

I know how to split and get the first part of a string i.e.

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.split("/").str[0]
```

but I am not sure how to impose the occurence condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the way you do the split. Split using the `alphanumerics` `immediately to the left of` `digit` followed by special character `/`followed by 4 `alphanumerics` and then pick first string in resulting list

```
df['URL']=df.URL.str.split('(?<=\d\/\w{4})\w+').str[0]

   

            URL
0  https://weibo.com/6402575118/Iy0z
1  https://weibo.com/6402575118/Hell
2  https://weibo.com/6402575118/hith
```

Answer (score 1):

If need repalce after 4.th occurence of `/` use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `n=4`, then join and add `5th` strings filtered for first `4` values in `str.cat`:

```
s = df['URL'].str.split("/", n=4)
df['URL'] = s.str[:4].str.join('/').str.cat(s.str[4].str[:4], '/')
print (df)
                                 URL
0  https://weibo.com/6402575118/Iy0z
1  https://weibo.com/6402575118/Hell
2  https://weibo.com/6402575118/hith
```

Another idea is split by `rsplit` from right side:

```
s = df['URL'].str.rsplit("/", n=1)
df['URL'] = s.str[0].str.cat(s.str[-1].str[:4], '/')
print (df)
                                 URL
0  https://weibo.com/6402575118/Iy0z
1  https://weibo.com/6402575118/Hell
2  https://weibo.com/6402575118/hith
```